# Cassandra - What precaustion should I take while deleting the backup files?

Tags: cassandra

As per documentation at http://docs.datastax.com/en/archived/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/operations/ops_backup_incremental_t.html,

```
As with snapshots, Cassandra does not automatically clear incremental backup files. DataStax recommends setting up a process to clear incremental backup hard-links each time a new snapshot is created.
```

So is it safe to trigger deleting all the files in backups directory immediately after invoking snapshot?

How can I check, whether snapshot was, not only invoked successfully, but also completed successfully?

What if I end-up deleting a backup hard-link which got created "just after" invoking the snapshot, but before the moment I triggered deletion of backup files?